# How to Access Special Keys ( Change Volume , Brightness , Lock , Sleep ) with a Keyboard that Doesnt have a Fn Key

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I Dont Have Fn Key in my Keyboard and the New Multimedia Keyboard is Not Suitable for My Working . Is there any Way to Access the Speacial Keys Without Fn Keys in my Keyboard .
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and my Keyboard is Old Dell Keyboard (Doesnt have Fn Key) .
Thank You :)

Comment: Anyone Pls Help me :(

Answer (score 1):

You can assign new key combinations in the keyboard settings. For example I mapped super ("windows key") + F11 to volume up. Now instead of Fn, I press super + the media key and it works!

See image: [Ubuntu Keyboard Shortcuts in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w52n6.png)

Comment: Thank You Bro , I Didnt Notice it in my Settings